# suddenly my android application crashes

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry guys for the newbie questions. I'm new to android, was working to set some login system in new application. Everything worked fine (after a long while), i had a login button from the menu in the main page which was just an empty "hello world" default activity. Then I decided to remove the "hello world" text view, i tried to run it immediately and the application crashed with null exception. I was doing ctrl+z like crazy but the application keeps on crashing. 
i understand absolutely nothing from the LogCat:

> 10-24 00:10:17.982: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   flg=0x10200000
>   cmp=com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity } 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59): HistoryRecord{4505f618
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity} failed creating
>   starting window 10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply
>   a layout_height attribute. 10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):
>     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3593)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:3672)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.(LinearLayout.java:1395)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1321)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:45)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620) 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407) 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2220)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1407)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:894)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   com.android.server.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9007)
>   10-24 00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-24
>   00:10:18.002: W/WindowManager(59):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-24 00:10:18.002:
>   W/WindowManager(59):  at
>   com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:570)
>   10-24 00:10:18.042: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication for activity
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity: pid=463
>   uid=10036 gids={3003} 10-24 00:10:18.272: D/AndroidRuntime(463):
>   Shutting down VM 10-24 00:10:18.272: W/dalvikvm(463): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate application
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication.mySoSpecialApplicationApplication:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:649)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4232)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-24
>   00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication.mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.(mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.java:14)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 10-24 00:10:18.292:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:644)
>   10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463):    ... 11 more 10-24
>   00:10:18.312: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity 10-24
>   00:10:18.968: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{4505f618
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity} 10-24
>   00:10:21.322: I/Process(463): Sending signal. PID: 463 SIG: 9 10-24
>   00:10:21.352: I/ActivityManager(59): Process
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication (pid 463) has died. 10-24
>   00:10:21.383: W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused,
>   ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44fc1780 10-24
>   00:10:29.087: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{4505f618
>   com.application.mySoSpecialApplication/.MainActivity}

Maybe one of you guys will figure out where is the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: The way to read the logcat output is to look for the last "caused by" stack trace. In this case, the logcat says that you got a NullPointerException from inside `getContentResolver` when you called it from line 14 of mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.java. You'll need to post the relevant code to get more help than that. :)

Comment: Or `Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute`.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yeah, that's probably it.

Answer (score 2):

here is something interesting:

W/WindowManager(59): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute. 1

you must specify layout_height in your layout views, its mandatory

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're missing an atribute you should have defined to some `View`.

So, to the XML layout inflated (the one you inflate when `setConentView(R.layout.this_one)` somewhere on the `onCreate()` method, I guess) just check if is missing the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. If so, please add it. This should resolve you issue.

> Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Comment: after trying to mess with the code I'm getting a much more frightening logcat. it doesn't contain now this message about missing layout_height, i guess I'll have to post it in another question. sorry for the mess. thank you very much for the help up until now guys.

Comment: Nope. my mistake, the same logcat. The thing is that I have no clue what is this binary xml file. the only xml file which is more than a few words is the AndroidManifest.xml file. The second two ones have android:layout_height="match_parent" in them and none of them is more than 14 lines. what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Incase of runtime error, look for   word   **Caused by:**   in your logcat.
This will help you to locate error easily.

Here in your case- look at logCat below...

```
00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90) 
10-24 00:10:18.292: E/AndroidRuntime(463): at com.application.mySoSpecialApplication.mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.(mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.java:14)
```

Ypu will find that run time error caused by **getContentResolver**   at   line 14  of **(mySoSpecialApplicationApplication.java:14)**
So here you located the error successfully.

After that  look at the explanation by **yugidroid**
This will help you.

I guess you're missing an atribute you should have defined to some View.
So, to the XML layout inflated (the one you inflate when setConentView(R.layout.this_one) somewhere on the onCreate() method, I guess) just check if is missing the android:layout_height="wrap_content". If so, please add it. This should resolve you issue.
    Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.